# How to execute code on remote server using SSH Tunnel?

Tags: python

I am using SSH tunnel to update my database on a remote server. I have a few queries regarding the the same.

Here is a sample code of the ssh tunnel.

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='your PythonAnywhere username', ssh_password='the password you use to log in to the PythonAnywhere website',
    remote_bind_address=('your PythonAnywhere database hostname, eg. yourusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='your PythonAnywhere username', password='your PythonAnywhere database password',
        host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database='your database name, eg yourusername$mydatabase',
    )
    # Do stuff
    connection.close()
```

Is the whole code inside the SSH tunnel (#do stuff here) executed on the remote server?
If I process some data on my computer outside of the SSH tunnel, is that data passed on to the remote server via the SSH tunnel?

I have a working example but a lot of my stuff is hacked. Just need to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is some help !

A little background - I have done some works which are similar to your use case. But my preferred choice of ssh tunnel is `paramiko`. Here is an example of how it works.

There is extensive paramiko API documentation you can find at: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/index.html

I use the following method to execute commands on a password protected client:

```
import paramiko
import sys

nbytes = 4096
hostname = 'hostname'
port = 22
username = 'username' 
password = 'password'
command = 'ls'

client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)

stdout_data = []
stderr_data = []
session = client.open_channel(kind='session')
session.exec_command(command)
while True:
    if session.recv_ready():
        stdout_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))
    if session.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(nbytes))
    if session.exit_status_ready():
        break

print 'exit status: ', session.recv_exit_status()
print ''.join(stdout_data)
print ''.join(stderr_data)

session.close()
client.close()
```

**My answers based on paramiko experience**

1. The only code that is executed in the remote server is that command that you passed to the `session` like `session.exec_command(command)`. I belive in your case, you need to pass it to `tunnel`
2. Yes, you can process some data in your local/host machine where this code is running. After processing that, you can construct new command and execute it as mention above.
3. No idea of your context, but if you want to do database operations on a remote server, your `mysql.connector.connect` can directly ssh and then connect to the database.